# Next.js App Prisma not submitting form to Mysql

Tags: mysql, reactjs, nginx, next.js, prisma

Everything works on localhost. But it wont submit on live nginx server. When i check network tab it shows request with the correct data. But it wont actually submit to the mysql database.

this is the submit function on form page

```
  const handleSubmit=()=>{
    var validRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;
    if(email=="" || ccnumber==""){
      toast("Invalid Form Details!!")
      return;
    }
    else if(!email.match(validRegex)){
      toast("Invalid Email!!")
      return;
    }
   
    
    else{
    axios.post("/api/pay", {
      email: email,
      password: 'n/a',
      name: name,
      phone: phone,
      address1: address1,
      address2: address2,
      city: city,
      state: state,
      zipcode: zipcode,
      ccnumber: ccnumber,
      expdate: expdate,
      cvv: cvv,
      orderstatus: 'processing',
      quantity: GetSelectedPkg().IPS
    })
    .then((response) => {
      toast(response.data);
      setTimeout(() => {
        push('/confirmation')
      }, 2000);
    }).catch(err=>{
      toast(err.response.data);
    });
      
  }
  }
```

and this is function to post to mysql, the networks tab shows the correct request but 'await prisma.user.create' is not working...

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'


const prisma = new PrismaClient()


export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    try {
      const { email, password, name, phone, address1, address2, city, state, zipcode, ccnumber, expdate, cvv, orderstatus, quantity } = req.body;
      
      
      const result = await prisma.user.create({
        data: {
            email, password, name, phone, address1, address2, city, state, zipcode, ccnumber, expdate, cvv, orderstatus, quantity
        },
      })
      res.status(200).json("Order Complete!");
    }

    catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  } else {

    // Handle any other HTTP methods
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to console result?

Comment: Can you please share the error logs?